# JNDI Lookup_problem for EJB 3 (ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

At first I want to inform that I know this is a common problem and I have gone through the previous solutions. But none is working.

I just want to create a HelloWorld application in EJB 3.0 using eclipse & jboss 7.1.1 Final.

Here is my bean:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldPack;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@Stateless(mappedName="HelloWorldBean")
public class HelloWorld implements HelloWorldRemote {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public HelloWorld() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void displayMsg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    System.out.println("Hello World!!");

}

}
```

Here is my remote interface:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldPack;

import javax.ejb.Local;
//import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorldRemote {

void displayMsg();
}
```

Here is my client:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldClient;

import java.util.Properties;

import com.tcs.HelloWorldPack.*;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class HelloWorldClient {

    private static final String LOOKUP_STRING = "HelloWorldBean";

    /*
     * location of JBoss JNDI Service provider the client will use. It should be
     * URL string.
     */
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "jnp://localhost:1099";

    /*s
     * specifying the list of package prefixes to use when loading in URL
     * context factories. colon separated
     */
    private static final String JNP_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces";

    /*
     * Factory that creates initial context objects. fully qualified class name.
     */
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";

    private static Context initialContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

        // Properties extends HashTable
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, JNP_INTERFACES);
        prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
        initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);

//      initialContext = new InitialContext();


        HelloWorldRemote hello = (HelloWorldRemote) initialContext.lookup(LOOKUP_STRING);


//      @EJB HelloWorldRemote hello;
        hello.displayMsg();
    }

}
```

But I am getting this exception while running the client:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at com.tcs.HelloWorldClient.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
    ... 4 more
```

Both the client & the bean is running in same computer.
I am very new to the EJB thing. Please explain what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check whether you have all the needed jars in the classpath